# Как задать необязательные поля pydantic в запросе для фастапи?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Модель pydantic:

```py
class FsEntityModel(BaseModel):
  name: str
  path: str # ./folder1/folder2/name
  type: Literal['file', 'folder']
  fileType: Optional[ Literal['img', 'txt', 'other'] ] # # not passed in request
  sizeInMB: Optional[ float ] # # not passed in request
```

Обработчик:

```py
# NEW FOLDER
class CreateNewFolderReqModel(BaseModel):
  fs_entity: FsEntityModel
  file_field: Literal['mere', 'unmere', 'reserved']

@router.post('/api/fs/create-new-folder', tags=['File system'])
def handle_create_new_folder(request: CreateNewFolderReqModel):
 # вызов контроллера до которого собсн даже не доходит
```

Так вот, если в req.body не включить fileType и sizeInMb, то pydantic вернет ошибку валидации:

```
тело запроса
{
  "fs_entity": {
    "name": "string",
    "path": "/",
    "type": "folder"
  },
  "file_field": "mere"
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

=> Как задать необязательные поля pydantic в запросе для фастапи?

Answer (score 1):

Для `Optional[]` полей прописал дефолтное значение = None

```py
class FsEntityModel(BaseModel):
  name: str
  path: str # ./folder1/folder2/name
  type: Literal['file', 'folder']
  fileType: Optional[ Literal['img', 'txt', 'other'] ] = None # # not passed in request
                                                       ^^^^^^
  sizeInMB: Optional[ float ] = None # # not passed in request
                              ^^^^^^
```

Вроде дало именно то что нужно

Comment: Да, в pydantic 2 нужно прописывать дефолтные значения для необязательных полей, раньше можно было оставить и так, он автоматом добавлял None.